# onRetrofitFailure() Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: android, json, api, kotlin, retrofit

I am given a Json data where an image and some other data is stored. I am trying to fetch that image in an imageview using Retrofit. I created a DTO of the required things as detailed in the code. I am getting and error, on retrofit failure. How can I solve this?

1. Created Retrofit Instance
2. Created DTO of JSON data and properties
3. API service created also
   https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/zestlife/promotional_banner.json
   Link where JSON data is stored.

   ```
   @Parcelize
   @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
   open class MerchantPromotionDTO(

       @JsonProperty("image") var image: ImageUrlsDTO? = null,
       @JsonProperty("cta") var cta: CTADTO? = null,
       @JsonProperty("probability") var probability: Int? = 0,
       @JsonProperty("isDismissible") var isDismissible: Boolean? = true,
       @JsonProperty("showImmediate") var showImmediate: Boolean? = false
       ) : BaseResponseDTO()

   @Parcelize
       @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
       class MerchantpromotionBDTO(
       @JsonProperty("promotions") var promotions: ArrayList<MerchantPromotionDTO>?=null
   ) : BaseResponseDTO()

   @GET("https://demo6861386.mockable.io/banner/test")
   fun getPromotionalBanner(): Call<ArrayList<MerchantpromotionBDTO>>

   fun getPromotionalDetails(): LiveData<ResponseDTO<ArrayList<MerchantpromotionBDTO>>>{
       val pBannerDetails=MutableLiveData<ResponseDTO<ArrayList<MerchantpromotionBDTO>>>()
       ApiComponent.enqueue({
           getPromotionalBanner(

           )
       },object :OnRequestComplete<ArrayList<MerchantpromotionBDTO>>{
           override fun onComplete(responseDTO: ResponseDTO<ArrayList<MerchantpromotionBDTO>>) {
               pBannerDetails.value=responseDTO
           }
       }
   )
   ```

EDIT:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    populateData()
}

@Synchronized
private fun populateData() {       
    MerchantpromotionBDTO?.let {
        val promImageUrl = it.image?.getImageUrl(CommonUtils.getDisplayDensityLevel(context))
        picasso.load(if (promImageUrl.isNullOrEmpty()) null else promImageUrl)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder_minimal)
                .into(ivMerchantPromotionBanner)
    }
}
```

I want the response into my logcat and to fetch an image in Imageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the JSON you're getting from the backend is:

```
{
    "promotions": [
        ...
    ]
}
```

Thas is a JSON object, not an array, but you defined `getPromotionalBanner` method as returning a `List<MerchantpromotionBDTO>`, so the JSON library cannot perform deserialisation as it expects an array (i.e. something starting with `[`) but it finds a START_OBJECT token (i.e., `{`).

You can solve the issue by changing the signature of that method to:

```
@GET("https://demo6861386.mockable.io/banner/test")
fun getPromotionalBanner(): Call<MerchantpromotionBDTO>
```

Comment: Hello sir,Thanks for responding on this query. The error of on RetrofitFailure wiped after i acted upon ur response but I am still not able to fetch an image from the given API.

Comment: I missed to add the picasso library code.. I have edited the que. Please see

Comment: If nothing happens - no errors/exceptions in the logcat and no image gets loaded - it could be caused by the promotional banner being `null`, as the `let` function wouldn't be called on it. The best way to investigate this problem is by debugging your code

Comment: I will see to it. Thanks  a lot for sir.